# How to resume normal scrolling after: window.onscroll = function () { window.scrollTo(0, 0);

Tags: javascript, ios, panel

I have a panel that opens but on IOS the body is scrolling behind the panel.

I am using `window.onscroll = function () { window.scrollTo(0, 0);` to stop the page scrolling behind the panel when the panel is open.

However, I need to resume normal scrolling afterwards in an event handler. What javascript can I use to resume normal scrolling? as currently when the panel is closed when you try to scroll you get positioned back to (0,0) of the window.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the panel is opened you set the onscroll function

```
window.onscroll = function () { window.scrollTo(0, 0);}
```

when the panel is closed:

```
window.onscroll = null;
```